# PDO connection refused when calling a function from schedule/kernel.php

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, pdo, eloquent

Good day. I am have a connection issue when I try to use schedule (Add code below in the kernel.php). Do I need to do something else to make it work. It works normal when u run it from the method from a route. But when when I run php artisan schedule:run it says Connection Refused.

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

Error above

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $controller = new \App\Http\Controllers\AdminController();
        $controller->getData();
        DB::table('users')->get();
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: @DinoNumić Yes I do. It works normally when from the regular controller. Its just when I try to call the function from Kernel.php

Comment: I jumped the gun too quickly. Deleted the comment after I saw that it works normal.